# Download file when available on the server

Tags: android, firebase

I need help regarding downloading a file in Android.
I want that a file be downloaded on users sd card when that file is available on the firebase data point.

I am confused as to how to start.

What I am currently thinking is.
I can have a service to download the file (set of images). Everyday once maybe I can hit the data point to know whether data is available, if available then the download starts else we stop.

I am not sure whether that is the most efficient way to do it.
Any guidance on this will be helpful.

Comment: first check internet connection than check is  that file available or not than after successfully check than download that file

Comment: you can also send a push notification to the client from the server once the file is available. It is way more efficient then checking the file every XXX minutes

Comment: Use push notification as suggested by @VladMatvienko. Checkout FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

Comment: Use a push notification to notify when to download

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Storage for storing custom files doesn't support events natively but Firebase Database does.

You can add the url of a file added in Firebase Storage to Firebase Database, and then use that to trigger events like onDataChange() or onChildAdded() which can be elegantly handled in your app.

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#value_events